# how to diagnose highly variable wifi performance from different devices all in the same room all to the same router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I installed fiber optic internet service last week, and installed the wifi router the provider-installer had with him because I didn't have another one handy.  The router is a TOTO LINK 300Mbps Wireless N Router model # N302R Plus.  The service is 100Mbps both up and down (I started with 50/50 and upgraded to 100/100 after I saw one of my devices was consistently hitting 50/50 on speedtest.net).

Within the same room, all of all my devices get these results consistently:

windows 10 Dell PC laptop Inspiron 13 5000 Series, Qualcomm QCA61x4A 802.11ac Wireless Adapter (bought this year): **48-50 down**, 80-90+ up. This device was getting ~50/~50 consistently before the upgrade to 100/100 and hoped it was hitting the provider throttling, but apparently was already at the down limit?

windows 7 Sony Vaio laptop, 9-10 years old, Atheros AR9285 wireless adapter, **80-90+ down, 80-90+ up**, this half-dead, probably malware-infested slow hunk of junk kicks wifi ass all over all the rest of my devices for some reason.

Google Pixel 2 smartphone [held next to router, didn't make a difference] (speedtest.net app): 24 down, 22 up

iphone 5c [held next to router, didn't make a difference] (speetest.net app): 36 down, 35 up

MacBookPro Retina: 11 down, 11 up from the router, 46 down / 46 up when connected to mobile hotspot on the Inspiron laptop next to it.   The MacBookPro of all the devices has tons of connectivity issues with the router.   Slow DNS, connections constantly drop, often can't connect to the router.  Dropped pings to external sites.  The Mac and the router just really seem to hate each other when directly connected.   No other device experiences these connection issues that the mac does.   On a wireless N  ASUS router, the macbook is absolutely fine on wifi with no connectivity issues.

I'm a career software guy and more or less comfortable tweaking the router advanced settings, but I'm not network hardware savvy so don't know where to start to figure out the speed limitations, and particular the horrible issues the mac has with the router in general.

Comment: Is "malware-infested slow hunk of junk" connected over WiFi or with help of ethernet cable? Actually you need some firewall/gateway/router that supports QoS/throttling/traffic-shaping then assign acceptable by your means to each device  allowed UP/DOWN bandwidth

Comment: @Alex As noted in the title, all devices are over wifi.   Sharing bandwidth among home devices is not the issue here, there are only one or two users,  but individually achieving the provider limit on each device.